# Why does the ScrollViewer property not affect a label?

Tags: c#, wpf

I use a `Label` with the `ScrollViewer` property:

```
<Label ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    Here is many many many text.
</Label>
```

But no scrollbar appears. Even when using `Visible` instead of `Auto`.

What is wrong here?

Comment: Is the label size somehow confined? For example by the container like a grid? Because if not, I think the label will simply grow to accomodate the text. The scrollbars only take effect if the label cannot grow any more.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the ScrollViewer around the label, it's a seperate control:

```
<ScrollViewer Width="50" Height="30" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Label>
        Here is many many many text.
    </Label>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Now I am wondering, why the Label can have ScrollViewer properties when they are not affecting the label at all?

Comment: I don't know, I'm interested in that too. I do you know you can apply ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility as a property to anything in WPF in XAML, but try creating a Label in codebehind, it's not available as a property to set.

Comment: I think it's the same as `Grid.Row` or `Grid.Column`, for them to have effect they have to be inside a Grid layout container.

Answer (score 5):

> Now I am wondering, why the Label can have ScrollViewer properties
>   when they are not affecting the label at all?

The ScrollViewer properties are attached properties. Attached properties often have default behavior that is independent from the elements they are applied to (e.g. `ToolTipService` properties are handled by the service, the elements themselves don't need to know anything about it), so they can always be set anywhere.

It's similar to the `BorderBrush` property that is on every control. A control usually passes this value along to a `Border` element that is within its template. Most control templates contain a Border, but many don't contain a ScrollViewer. You could write a Label template that includes one, though:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Label">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <ScrollViewer>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<Label ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
       ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
       Content="text" />
```

Notice that this works even though I haven't added `TemplateBinding`s to the `ScrollViewer`. This is because `ScrollViewer` knows about its own attached properties and actually adds the bindings by default if it is inside a template.

As you can see from the template, a label is really nothing but a content presenter with [RecognizesAccessKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.recognizesaccesskey.aspx) set. This is so that users can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> keyboard shortcuts based on its text. `Label` also defines a `Target` property to define which element should be selected when the keyboard shortcut is pressed. Labels are meant to be short descriptive text next to input elements. In your case (displaying long text that needs scrolling), it is probably unnecessary. In fact, you can just place the text content directly within a ScrollViewer:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    Here is many many many text.
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 4):

`ScrollViewer` attached property is there to control `ScrollViewer` which was defined within the control's `Template` (first example of such control which comes to mind is `ListView`). There is no `ScrollViewer` in `Label`'s template, therefore setting this property on label has no effect.

Instead, you should simply wrap your `Label` with `ScrollViewer`, as was shown by JMK.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the lable inside the ScrollViewer and provide some Height and Width

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="40" Width="40" >

   <Label>
      Content
   </Label>

</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put ScrollViewer around the Label.
 like--

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">

   <Label/>

</ScrollViewer>
```